# Is there a better way to specify default section content in asp.net mvc razor layouts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

With the asp.net mvc web form engine, you could define a content placeholder and specify the default content.  How is this done with Razor engine?

I found this example in Phil Haack's [Defining Default Content For A Razor Layout Section](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx/) - but it seems like there would be a better way.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Footer")) 
{ 
  @RenderSection("Footer") 
} 
else 
{ 
  <text>Default footer text here</text> 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

I looked into writing an Html helper but the view isn't available to the htmlHelper and I haven't been able to see a way, at least right away, that would allow you to do it. It might be something worth requesting on http://aspnet.codeplex.com as I've seen others request this functionality on a couple of the blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh.. stupid Razor (I actually like it). Maybe MS will find a better way? Smth like:
@RenderSection("Footer", () => 

{

  blah...

})